# Maven WAR deploy

Tags: java, maven, web-services

I would need the advice of a Maven expert :
I have a project that I want to deploy to a Glassfish/Payara server via SFTP using the `mvn clean package command -Denv=rec deploy`

This is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>fr.inrae.sicpa</groupId>
  <artifactId>TraceLBSoapWS</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <properties>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.version>3.1</maven.compiler.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.jws/jakarta.jws-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.jws</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.jws-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <profiles>
    <!-- Profil pour l'environnement de recette -->
    <profile>
      <id>rec</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>env</name>
          <value>rec</value>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <resources>
          <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/resources/rec</directory>
          </resource>
        </resources>
      </build>
      <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
         <id>my-server-recette</id>
         <url>sftp://my.server.fr:/data/apps/payara/autodeploy/group-recette/webdistri</url>
        </repository>
      </distributionManagement>
    </profile>
     <!-- Profil pour l'environnement de production -->
    <profile>
      <id>prod</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>env</name>
          <value>prod</value>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <resources>
          <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/resources/prod</directory>
          </resource>
        </resources>
      </build>
      <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
         <id>my-server-production</id>
         <url>sftp://my.server.fr:/data/apps/payara/autodeploy/group-production/webdistri</url>
        </repository>
      </distributionManagement>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

  <build>
    <finalName>TraceLBSoapWS</finalName>
    <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>${basedir}/test</testSourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>${basedir}/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <includes>
          <include>*.properties</include>
          <include>*.xml</include>
        </includes>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>11</source>
          <target>11</target>
          <release>11</release>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>${basedir}/WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <!-- exclude web.xml file -->
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
          <warSourceExcludes>WEB-INF/web.xml</warSourceExcludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <extensions>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.wagon/wagon-ssh -->
      <extension>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
        <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
      </extension>
    </extensions>
  </build>
</project>
```

Unfortunately, when I launch my maven command, it's not the WAR that is deployed but all the project. **How could I deploy only the WAR to my Glassfish/Payara server ?**

Thanks for your answers

Thierry

---

EDIT : The request I got: *"Using maven, compile, test, package and deploy the war archive in the autodeploy folder of payara"*

Comment: distributionManagement is for specifying repositories to deploy artifacts to. Look at the wagon upload goal.

Comment: The command `deploy` is meant to upload something to Nexus or Artifactory, not for deploying on servers.

Comment: Why have you changed the defaults `<sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src</sourceDirectory>`?? Usually it does not make sense...keep the conventions.. To deploy to application server you might use: https://github.com/probedock/glassfish-maven-plugin and not Maven itself as already mentioned distributionManagement is intended to deploy to an repo manager...

Comment: Thank you tgdavies, J Fabian Meier, khmarbaise,

To answer @khmarbaise, I'm writing a documentation for the migration of existing webservices to maven. These historical webservices don't respect the tree structure created by maven but remain functional. What I was asked to do is to be able to migrate existing webservices with as few changes as possible, changes that could jeopardize their operation.

I'm going to take a look at the tracks you all gave me and which seem to go in the same direction.

Comment: Okay, this plugin is not a solution for me. When I read you, I thought it allowed to deploy the archive via sftp but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: The request I got: "Using maven, compile, test, package and deploy the war archive in the autodeploy folder of payara".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the track piece that @tgdavies gave me *(thank you very much)*, I managed to do what I wanted to do using the `org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-ssh` extension and the `org.codehaus.mojo:wagon-maven-plugin` plugin together

here's how I configured it in my pom.mxl :

```
    <extensions>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.wagon/wagon-ssh -->
      <extension>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
        <artifactId> wagon-ssh</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
      </extension>
    </extensions>
```

```
    </plugins>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo/wagon-maven-plugin -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId> car-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>rec</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goyals
              <goal>upload-single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <fromFile>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}</fromFile>
              <url>scp://user@my.server.fr:/data/apps/payara/autodeploy/group-recette</url>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

And here is the command to compile, test, package and deploy :

```
mvn clean package -Denv=rec wagon:upload-single@rec
```

Hoping that my answer can help other people with this specific need.

Have a nice day

Thierry